# How to reformulate this model in standard form?

Tags: linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, duality-theorems

How to reformulate the following linear programming model into an equivalent model that is a linear program in standard form?:

Maximize $-e^T |x|$
subject to $Ax \geq b$
x unrestricted

where e = (1, 1,...,1)
and |x| = abs(x)

Standard form in this case would be:

$min_x$ $c^Tx$
Ax = b
x $\geq$ 0

Comment: Suppose you have $4$ (decision) variables is then your objective function $-|x_1|-|x_2|-|x_3|-|x_4|$?

Comment: I guess so, I also find it an odd formulation. It is mainly about the formulation. I have a hunch that the absolute value in the objective can be exchanged with the $\geq$ in the standard form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tranform the variables $|x_j|=x_j^++x_j^-$ and $x_j=x_j^+-x_j^-$ , with $x_j^+,x_j^-\geq 0$

For 2 decision variables and 2 constraints we get

$\texttt{max} \ \ -x_1^+-x_1^--x_2^+-x_2^- $

$a_{11}\cdot \left( x_1^+-x_1^-\right)+a_{12}\cdot \left( x_2^+-x_2^-\right)\geq b_1$

$a_{21}\cdot \left( x_1^+-x_1^-\right)+a_{22}\cdot \left( x_2^+-x_2^-\right)\geq b_2$

$x_1^+,x_1^-,x_2^+,x_2^-\geq 0$

- Maximizing $f(\textbf x)$ is equivalent to minimizing $-f(\textbf x)$
- And we have to subtract surplus variables ($s_i$) for each
  $\geq$-constraint to get equations.

$\texttt{min} \ \ x_1^++x_1^-+x_2^++x_2^- $

$a_{11}\cdot \left( x_1^+-x_1^-\right)+a_{12}\cdot \left( x_2^+-x_2^-\right)-s_1=b_1$

$a_{21}\cdot \left( x_1^+-x_1^-\right)+a_{22}\cdot \left( x_2^+-x_2^-\right)-s_2= b_2$

$x_1^+,x_1^-,x_2^+,x_2^-,s_1,s_2\geq 0$

This is what you wanted.

Comment: You also need $s_i \ge 0$.

Comment: And subtract $s_i$ instead of adding.

Comment: @RobPratt 100% right. No idea why I´ve witten it this way.

Comment: Looks good now.

Comment: what would be a numbered example?

Comment: / for $^+_1,^−_1,^+_2,^−_2,_1,_2$

Comment: Just replace the coefficient by some numbers. For instance: $a_{11}=1,a_{12}=2,a_{21}=3,a_{22}=1, b_1=-1, b_2=7$

Comment: but are $x^- and x^+$ opposites, like -4 and +4?

Comment: Not really. One of them will be $0$ at the optimal solution. Note that both are non-negative. If the solution is $x^{-}=4$ and $x^{+}=0$ then $x=-4$